# google charts change background color

Tags: charts, background, google-visualization, background-color

I saw some previous questions/answers here on StackOverflow
but none of the code provided in those answers seemed to work
with my chart:
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['January', 200, 150],
      ['February', 1170, 460],
      ['March', 660, 1120],
      ['April', 1030, 540],
      ['May', 1030, 540],
      ['June', 1030, 540]
    ]);

    var options = {

          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: May-August',
            backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',
          }

    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

The html div code:

```
<div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 650px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

The thing is I want to change the background from white to light gray
and I can't seem to make it work by declaring backgroundColor: "#fcfcfc'
inside options{}

Is there any other way to declare a background color on that chart
I'm thinking maybe the type of chart I'm using can't change it's
background color.

I also tried to specify the backgroundColor variable as a function (followed by curly brackets backgroundColor{ color: '#fcfcfc' }
but that didn't work on my chart either.

Any help would be higly appreciated.
Thank you

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mtypsnqy/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you've placed your `backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',` at the wrong place. You have defined it inside of `chart:{}`while you should do it either outside any object or inside of `chartArea` like:

```
var options = {
   chart: {
     title: 'Company Performance',
     subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: May-August'
   },
   backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc'
};
```

which will cause your whole div containing the chart to be dark grey or like this:

```
var options = {
   chart: {
     title: 'Company Performance',
     subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: May-August'
   },
   chartArea:{
      backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc'
  }
};
```

which will cause only the area contained within your two axes to be colored red.

And finally you have to change your

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

to

```
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

as specified on the [Bar Charts API page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart).

I made you a fiddle to play around in and see the difference: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/wx843ysq/)

Comment: Thank you Henrik. Actually I tried the first option you proposed and nothing happened. Clearly I had to modify the chart.draw() func for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This was the part I was missing: chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options)); ... thanks.

Comment: I saw a ton of answers for similiar problems but none included  `chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));` that did the trick. Thank you